# What SQL script or SSMS feature will change my login password when I am not sa

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I am not sa, I own a database and I can log in to the server through SSMS. What SQL statement can I write to change my own login password or is there a way to do it through the SSMS interface?

Comment: You can do it through SSMS but that still executes an ALTER LOGIN. You can even inspect the generated SQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change your password using T-SQL, use [ALTER LOGIN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-login-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#c-changing-the-password-of-a-login-when-logged-in-as-the-login). Login as normal and specify both your old and new password:

```
ALTER LOGIN YourLogin
    WITH PASSWORD = '<your-new-password>'
    OLD_PASSWORD = '<your-old-password>';
```